# py.test fixtures creation best practices

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I'm rather new to unit-testing and py.test.

I have question about testing. 
I need to format datas which came from a webservices.
These datas (xml, json or whatever) need to be processed, some part need to be extracted and returned as a built-in python type (list, dict, collection, ...).

If I need to create a test method which would check if the data is well formated, do I need to use fixtures which come from directly from the webservices or do I need to create my fixtures from a representation of data provided from the webservices?

For example:

tests.py

```
def test_well_formated_data(the_fixture):
    assert isintance(formatting_method(the_fixture), list)
    # and other assertion...
```

conftests.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def the_fixture()
    return Webservices.connect()
```

Or for the representation:

```
@pytest.fixture
def the_fixture()
    # Here is the same string returned by the webservices
    # each time it's called
    return "{'foo': [ 'bar', 'spam', 'egg']}"
```

In some books or tutorial I have read, the purpose is to check if a input is treated and returned as expected. For the input a "snapshot" of data at the moment is sufficient.

So do I create fixture from an 'immutable' datas and not be aware of changed datas send by the webservices, or do I need to create fixture which will be, in this case, the nearest of the reality but with the risk to be too dependent of an external behaviour (like, 404, 500 error for exemple)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you do not test against external services, but rather make sure that your own application is correct in processing and handling.

In your case, you can *monkey-patch* the webservice (i.e. implement a dummy that returns a few data snippets) and test whether your code handles them as expected.

Comment: Ok thanks, so like I thought I need to create data snippet which is like the original.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'll use a test data fixture to set up some data that's either static or expressible programmatically.

When I write unit tests for interactions with external services, usually I'll manually call the external service and save off the response. Then I'll create a test fixture that returns the response -- it's this fixture that I'll use in my tests.

What fixture data you should use really depends on your code that you're most interested in testing. For example, if your code is parsing a JSON response, do you want to define your fixture data as the raw JSON (i.e. `'{"foo": "bar"}'`) or as the parsed JSON (i.e. `{'foo': 'bar'}`)? It's up to you based on your judgment of what's most important to test.